# Grouping string ListView on Android?

Tags: android, string, listview, grouping

I have string like this :

```
you
me
i
me
i
i
you
me
me
```

I want to group that string in my ListView like this :

```
you (2)
me (4)
i (3)
```

and if I click "you (2)", show ListView again like this :

```
you
you
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Please provide you code so that we can give best solution ...other this can easy done using collections.......

Answer (score 1):

First you need to sort your list adapter. For sorting this will be useful for you http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/alphabetical-listview-in-android-t56983.html

Then implement [expandable list](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html)

As Dheeresh Singh said, please work on some code and then we can help more. Thanks